# Where to download fischer random games?

Tags: chess-variants, pgn, chess960

Where can I download the PGN files for the World Chess 960 championship from 2019, that was won by Wesley So?

I can view the games on the website e.g, https://www.frchess.com/stream but I want to download the games onto my own machine. pgnmentor and chessgames do not seem to have recorded these games (only "classical chess" games)

Comment: where does agadmator get it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spj5to6PgLI https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/fide-world-fischer-random-chess-championship-2019 well of course Brian Towers♦ shortcuts the whole thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goto site for downloadable pgns for regular chess is Mark Crowther's "[The Week in Chess](https://theweekinchess.com/)". The good news is that he also covers 960 or Fischer Random. This is [TWIC's page](https://theweekinchess.com/chessnews/events/world-fischer-random-chess-championship-2019) for the World Fischer Random Chess Championship 2019.

The link for the pgn files is [here](https://theweekinchess.com/assets/files/pgn/fischerr19.pgn).

Answer (score 0):

Semi-finals and finals:

You can try looking up 'chess960', '960' , '9LX', 'chess9LX', 'chess 9LX', 'chess 960' or 'fischer random' in lichess studies

https://lichess.org/study

for example you can find the 2019 FIDE fischer random world championship finals here

https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-finals-game-1/-/DM0hC3u1

eg

i counted [number of pawns at start of endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37436/on-average-how-many-pawns-are-there-at-the-start-of-the-endgame) for each of the finals games

https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-finals-game-1/-/DM0hC3u1

1 - [9](https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-finals-game-1/-/DM0hC3u1)

2 - [6](https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-finals-game-2/-/QyqmRYgT)

3 - [12](https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-finals-game-3/-/SHljkTy4)

4 - [5](https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-finals-game-4/-/AS8MuiPN)

5 - [N/A](https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-finals-game-5/-/TYRLiqxv)

6 - [N/A](https://lichess.org/broadcast/fischer-random-championship-finals-game-6/-/xhpI3MtT)

---

Quarter-finals:

They were played on chesscom

https://www.chess.com/games/archive/gmwso?gameOwner=other_game&gameType=live&gameTypeslive%5B%5D=liveChess960&endDate%5Bdate%5D=10/31/2019&startDate%5Bdate%5D=10/01/2019&timeSort=desc&opponentTitle=any